# sockjs - example of implementing rooms

Tags: python, tornado, sockjs

I would like to have users create and join a "rooms" so that they can collaborate.

I'm looking at [SockJs Multiplexer server](https://github.com/sockjs/websocket-multiplex) and wondering if I can leverage some of that to create and broadcast to specific channel/room.

In the example, a [channel is created manually](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/blob/master/examples/multiplex/server.js#L15) and [client connects to that channel](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/blob/master/examples/multiplex/index.html#L86).

Would treating these channels as rooms work?

Is there a way to dynamically create these channels instead of manually declaring them on server?

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer:  I didn't notice that you were referring to the Javascript-version of the server until I had written my answer.  Therefore, my code examples are given using the Python-based [sockjs-tornado](https://github.com/MrJoes/sockjs-tornado), but I guess the principles should be the same.

Yes, you may treat the channels as rooms by keeping a set of referenced connections in each `SockJSConnection`-derived class.  To do that, all you would need is to change each connection class slightly from

```py
class AnnConnection(SockJSConnection):
    def on_open(self, info):
        self.send('Ann says hi!!')

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.broadcast(self.connected, 'Ann nods: ' + message)
```

to

```py
class AnnConnection(SockJSConnection):
    connected = WeakSet()

    def on_open(self, info):
        self.connected.add(self)
        self.send('Ann says hi!!')

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.broadcast(self.connected, 'Ann nods: ' + message)

    def on_close(self):
        self.connected.remove(self)
        super(AnnConnection, self).on_close()
```

in [server.py](https://github.com/mrjoes/sockjs-tornado/blob/master/examples/multiplex/server.py#L24).

To create the channels dynamically, I changed the `__main__` code and `MultiplexConnection` class slightly and added a couple of new classes.  In the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block,

```py
# Create multiplexer
router = MultiplexConnection.get(ann=AnnConnection, bob=BobConnection,
                                 carl=CarlConnection)
```

was changed to

```py
# Create multiplexer
router = MultiplexConnection.get()
```

While

```py
class MultiplexConnection(conn.SockJSConnection):
    channels = dict()
    # …

    def on_message(self, msg):
        # …
        if chan not in self.channels:
            return
```

in [MultiplexConnection](https://github.com/mrjoes/sockjs-tornado/blob/master/examples/multiplex/multiplex.py#L49) was changed to

```py
class MultiplexConnection(conn.SockJSConnection):
    channels = dict()
    _channel_factory = ChannelFactory()
    # …

    def on_message(self, msg):
        # …
        if chan not in self.channels:
            self.channels[chan] = self._channel_factory(chan)
```

and the classes

```py
class DynamicConnection(SockJSConnection):
    def on_open(self, info):
        self.connected.add(self)
        self.send('{0} says hi!!'.format(self.name))

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.broadcast(self.connected, '{0} nods: {1}'
            .format(self.name, message))

    def on_close(self):
        self.connected.remove(self)
        super(DynamicConnection, self).on_close()


class ChannelFactory(object):
    _channels = dict()

    def __call__(self, channel_name):
        if channel_name not in self._channels:
            class Channel(DynamicConnection):
                connected = WeakSet()
                name = channel_name

            self._channels[channel_name] = Channel

        return self._channels[channel_name]
```

were added to [multiplex.py](https://github.com/mrjoes/sockjs-tornado/blob/master/examples/multiplex/multiplex.py).

Comment: Hi Martin, Am facing trouble making my chat interactions private (one to one). Could you kindly have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461046/private-messaging-using-sockjs-tornado/34463050#34463050 ?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, Sathish.  I just wrote my [suggested solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34466792/126273).