# Private messaging using sockjs-tornado

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, tornado, sockjs-tornado

I have implemented chat feature using sockjs-tornado and could store the messages in RethinkDB.

Could you please help me on how do I establish private channel for messaging in sockjs-tornado ? (I mean Private conversation / one to one)

Below is the on_message function in my server side code -

```
def on_message(self, message):
    str=message
    mg=str.split('#:#')
    sender=1 # This is the sender user id
    receiver=2 #This is the receiver user id - I need to implement session variables to have these id's so that I can use it here this way
    ts=r.expr(datetime.now(r.make_timezone('00:00')))
    connection = r.connect(host="192.x.x.x")
    r.db("djrechat").table('events').insert({"usrs":mg[0],"msg":mg[1],"tstamp":ts,"snder":sender,"rcver":receiver}).run(connection)
    log.info(message)
    self.broadcast(self.participants, '{} - {}'.format(self.stamp(),message))
```

Currently this is broadcasting to all the clients connected.
May be I should have a channel id and to send message only to the two clients which will have the same channel id, but how do I implement it or is there any better solution for this?

At client side, I have below javascript -

```
      function connect() {
        disconnect();
        conn = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/chat', ['websocket','xhr-streaming','iframe-eventsource','iframe-htmlfile','xhr-polling','iframe-xhr-polling','jsonp-polling']);
        //log('Connecting.....');
        conn.onopen = function() {
        //  log('Connected. (' + conn.protocol + ')');
        log('Connected.');
        };

        conn.onmessage = function(e) {
          log(e.data);
        };

        conn.onclose = function() {
          log('Disconnected.');
          conn = null;
        };
      }
```

Am using python 3.4 - Django 1.8.4 and Rethinkdb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer makes the assumption that all clients in the current solution connect to a SockJS server with a channel name that is used for broadcasts of the chat messages (or something close to this scenario).  I further assume that the round-trip when a user sends a message from the client is:

```
[Sender (Client)] ------- Message (POST) --> [App Server] --- Message --> [Database]
                                                  |
                                               Message
                                                  v
[Receiver(s) (Client)] <-- Message (WS) -- [SockJS Server]
```

There are multiple solutions to this problem.  I will only outline the one I think is simplest and most robust here:

- **Let every user subscribe to a *per-user* (private) channel *in addition* to the broadcast-channel in the chat.**  If you implement this solution, the only *additional* change is to make the **app server** aware of private messages which must be sendt *only* to the receiver's **private** channel.

Another, slightly more complex, and inelegant solution would be to **create *ad hoc* channels for each private pair when needed.**  However, how would you get `User B` to subscribe to the (newly created) private channel when `User A` wants to chat with `User B`?  One way would be to **broadcast** a request for `User B` to connect to that channel, but that would tell all the other clients (at the code level) about this private chat that will take place; and if any of those clients are compromised, that information can be misused for, for example, eavesdropping or crashing the private party.

### Additional Advice

I would also like to mention that since I wrote my [sockjs - example of implementing rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16539485/126273) answer, I have changed my own architecture to (still) use `SockJS` in the front-end, but with [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) using the [Web-STOMP plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html) on the back-end.  That way,

1. the client still uses **[sockjs-client](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client)** with [stomp-websocket](https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket) in the browser,
2. all of the back-end code to handle *front-end multiplexing* **could be removed**,
3. the (RabbitMQ-based) back-end is **fast** and **really robust**,
4. the client POSTs a message to the back-end app server, which in turn

   1. persists the message in the database, *and*
   2. acts as a client of the RabbitMQ server and either **(1)** broadcasts the message to all connected users, or if the message is **private** **(2)** sends the message to a single recipient over the recipient's own private channel, as sketched out in the above suggested solution.

The whole new solution is placed behind HAProxy which terminates HTTPS and SSL/TLS-encrypted WebSocket connections.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin for sharing the useful information!

Comment: I will try to adapt the first one which I thought of earlier but wasn't sure how to make my server to identify the incoming msg is via private channel and push the msg only to that private channeled client.. I will try the implementation.

Comment: Hi Martin, Could you please help me with the private messaging code?  I tried in different ways but couldn't implement it for one to one messaging. RabbitMQ based is also fine.. Only thing is it should be python 3.4 supported

Comment: @Sathish, have you started using RabbitMQ with Web-STOMP in the back-end, like I advised above?  Because if so, since RabbitMQ version 3.5.7 (or, even better 3.6.0), implementing the private channels has become even easier.  Knowing this would help me write my pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

Although sockjs-tornado does not implement such a thing like channels, nor rooms, there is [example multiplex](https://github.com/mrjoes/sockjs-tornado/tree/master/examples/multiplex) how one could implement that. Also look at [sockjs - example of implementing rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023933/sockjs-example-of-implementing-rooms). Solution is based on structured `msg` - within message you additional info is sent - channel name.

Comment: I tried using conn.send({'method': 'set-channel', 'data': {'channel': channel_id}}) , channel_id is combination of 'senderid&receiverid' inside my onopen event at client side.. But it fails and I see no error in console.. Not sure how I can implement one to one messaging

Comment: Checking the rooms example if it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for the examples!